# Gerar CSS apartir dos css inline dos elementos DOM

Tags: css

Olá,
fiz um documento, grande, cheio de css inline, e sei que misturar css com html, usando o atributo style direto no elemento é uma má prática..

Mas e agora, têm um jeito de gerar um css comum, único, agrupando todos os css inlines?
Ou neste caso o negocio é fazer no braço?

Comment: Tente isto. É uma solução online: http://www.cssout.com/

Comment: Caso funcione, avisa.

Comment: dreamweaver: http://helpx.adobe.com/dreamweaver/using/convert-inline-css-css-rule.html

Answer (score 3):

O [Dreamweaver](http://helpx.adobe.com/br/dreamweaver/using/convert-inline-css-css-rule.html) tem uma ferramenta para isso.

1. Na Visualização de código (Exibir > Código), selecione o atributo de estilo inteiro que contenha a CSS inline a ser convertida.
2. Clique com o botão direito do mouse e selecione Estilos CSS > Converter CSS inline em regra.
3. Na caixa de diálogo Converter CSS inline, digite um nome de classe para a nova regra e siga um destes procedimentos:

   - Especifique uma folha de estilos na qual a nova regra CSS deve aparecer e clique em OK.
   - Selecione o cabeçalho do documento como o local onde a nova regra CSS deve aparecer e clique em OK.
   - Também é possível converter as regras usando a barra de ferramentas Codificação. A barra de ferramentas Codificação está disponível somente na Visualização de código.

[Fonte](http://helpx.adobe.com/br/dreamweaver/using/convert-inline-css-css-rule.html)